# Let $k$ and $n$ be positive integers, find all pairs $(n,k)$ of positive integers such that $(n+1)^k-1=n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponentiation, factorial

> Let $k$ and $n$ be positive integers, find all pairs $(n,k)$ of positive integers such that $(n+1)^k-1=n!$

I tried $n$ from $1$ to $4$, and I guess $n$ should be a prime number.

Comment: Well, as a quick remark:  if $n$ is odd then the left hand is odd but the right hand is even.

Comment: @lulu Except for $n=k=1$.

Comment: @ajotatxe  Sure.  I was mostly addressing the suggestion that $n$ ought to be prime.

Comment: The equation is equivalent to: $$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+1)^j=(n-1)!$$ So if $n$ is prime we get $k\equiv -1\pmod n$. If $n$ is composite we get $n\mid k$. Then $k\ge n-1$. This might help.

Comment: Also worth noting:  if $p<n+1$ is a prime dividing $n+1$ then $p$ divides the right hand but not the left.  Thus $n+1$ has to be prime.

Comment: See also: [Solve $n!=(n+1)^k-1$ for $n,k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2825943)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve $n!=(n+1)^k-1$ for $n,k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825943/solve-n-n1k-1-for-n-k)

Answer (score 2):

If $n+1$ is composite, then any prime dividing $n+1$ divides $n!$, but not $(n+1)^k-1$. Then $n+1$ is prime. Therefore, $n\le 2$ or $n$ is composite.

For $n=1$ we get easily the solution $n=k=1$.

For $n=2$ the equation becomes
$$3^k-1=2$$
which clearly has only one solution, namely $k=1$.

So assume from now that $n$ is composite.

If $n=4$ the equation becomes
$$5^k-1=24$$
that has the solution $k=2$.

If $n\ge 6$ then $(n-1)!$ is a multiple of $n$. Proof below.

The equation is equivalent to: $$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(n+1)^j=(n-1)!$$ So, since $n$ is composite, taking mod $n$ we get $n\mid k$. Then $k\ge n$. Thus,

$$(n+1)^k-1\ge(n+1)^n-1>n^n>n!$$

So there are no more solutions.

*Proof that $n\ge 6$ and composite implies $n\mid (n-1)!$*: If $n$ is the square of a prime $p$ then $p$ and $2p$ are among the factors of $(n-1)!$. Otherwise take the least prime divisor $p$ and $n/p$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why the equation is equivalent to the summation.

Comment: Just factor out an $n$ out of $n!$ and factor $(n+1)^k-1$ as $n((n+1)^{k-1}+...+1)$ @claxxy