# Solve $n!=(n+1)^k-1$ for $n,k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all integer $(n,k)$ such that 
>   $n!=(n+1)^k-1$

**My Attempt**
.                   Let $(n+1)=p$.
Therefore,$ L.H.S. \equiv {-1}\pmod p$ and $R.H.S. \equiv {-1}\pmod p$.
So,$k=log_{p} ^{(p-1)!+1}$.
Now we have to set the values of $p$ in order to find integer $k$.
I am not satisfied  of my answer.I believe that better answer is there.I didn't complete my answer because I considered a certain case(i.e. $n+1$ is a prime).I must consider more cases but i failed to find them! 
Please help me!

Comment: For composite $n+1>0$ all of the proper divisors $d$ will have $d<n$. So if $n+1$  has no square factors $n!$ is zero mod $n+1$. So I'd focus on squares.

Comment: If $n+1$ is prime then $n!+1$ will be a *multiple* of $n+1$, but it seems unlikely that it will be a *power* of $n+1$. The only examples I can think of are $2! + 1 = 3^1$ and $4!+1=5^2$.

Comment: By Wilson's theorem, $n+1$ must be a prime.

Comment: See also: [Let $k$ and $n$ be positive integers, find all pairs $(n,k)$ of positive integers such that $(n+1)^k-1=n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2475231)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $n>2$ and $k>0$.

1. $n^k \leq (n+1)^k-1=n!<n^n$ so that $k<n$.
2. If $n=ab$ for some $a \neq b$, then $n!$ contains the terms $a,b,ab$ in the product and hence is divisible by $n^2$. OTOH the R.H.S. is equal to $kn$ modulo $n^2$, that is: $n$ divides $k$, contradicting 1.
3. Unless $n$ is of the form $p^2$, $n$ has a representation as in 2. Since $n$ is even, for $n>4$, $n$ is not of the form $p^2$ and thus there is no solution for $n>4$.